# UICollectionViewCell changes height when keyboard appears swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been working on an app that has a UICollectionView that works like the main screen with the UICollectionViewCells acting as different pages (scrolling horizontally). I have added a text field on each cell to edit, but when I click on the textfield, the cell height is extended when the keyboard appears. When the keyboard is hidden the cell height remains extended. I have been searching for an answer to this problem, but I have not come across a solution that works.

I have tried to invalidate the layout, set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false, and directly setting the content offset to zero. None of these options have fixed the issue.

Below is my code:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = ["Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3", "Cell4", "Cell5"]

let navi_btn_array: [UIButton] = [navi_home_btn, navi_gavel_btn, navi_orders_btn, navi_profile_btn, navi_lightning_btn]
var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    var cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout);
    cv.autoresizesSubviews = false
    cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    return cv;
}();

class MainCVC: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        collectionView?.register(SimpleDispensaryPage_Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier[0])
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        let nc:NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
        nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification){

        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView?.contentOffset.y = 0


    }
    @objc func keyboardDidHide(notification: Notification){

        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView?.contentOffset.y = 0

    }



    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5

    }
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier[0], for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = Custom_Colors.color_pine.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            var txt_fld = UITextField()
            txt_fld.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50)
            cell_label.text = "Placeholder #"+String(indexPath.item)
            cell_label.textAlignment = .center
            cell.addSubview(cell_label)
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

I also get this error when it runs:

```
2019-03-14 11:41:20.770799-0700 app[57379:5390785] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2019-03-14 11:41:20.771043-0700 app[57379:5390785] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fda15c13f40>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fda1706f000; frame = (0 0; 375 730.8); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000447bc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000437720>; contentOffset: {8, -38.333333333333336}; contentSize: {1891, 579}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 151.79999999999995, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fda15c13f40>.
2019-03-14 11:41:20.771245-0700 app[57379:5390785] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: Change the offset value of y in keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide method.

Comment: Do I have it set incorrectly in the code above? Also will that help maintain the original height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little bit of strange setup here. I suggest making a couple of changes:

1 - Never add subviews in collectionView(_, cellForItemAt ...). This would result in multiple additions every time the cell is being reused. The subviews should be added by the cell (and preferably at creation time).

2 - Remove `cv.autoresizesSubviews = false` and `cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

3 - If you want a fixed size for your cells you can set the `layout.delegate = self` and implement the following method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
}
```

4 - If you really just want a couple of pages why don't you use UIPageViewController?

Comment: I did figure out how to correct the sizing, but this was actually a much cleaner approach. Thank you!